# How to Make a Pentagram with CSS Border Attributes

Tags: border, css

I'm making a website for death metal promos and was wondering if it was possible to make a pentagram in CSS3 using border attributes. I was able to find some references that lead me to believe it was possible to make a six-point star, but after several hours of mental torment I have given up on making a 5 point star. Is this possible?

A hexagram consists of two triangles and thats how css3 can pull it off with the following code:

```
#six-point-star {
   position: absolute;
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-left: 50px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 50px solid transparent; 
   border-bottom: 80px solid black;
}
#six-point-star:after {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-left: 50px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 50px solid transparent; 
   border-top: 80px solid black;
   margin: 30px 0 0 -50px;
}
```

But it gets confusing with 5 points because it can't be broken up into smaller polygons. Any knowledge as to how I could implement this would be great.

http://jsfiddle.net/8FjL2/1/

http://www.skinit.com/assets/seo/jumbo_shot/jumbo_shot50039084/pentagram.jpg

Comment: Your fiddle is not set up correctly.

Comment: Just because it is possible to do things with elaborate combinations of CSS3 and elements doesn't mean you should. Use an SVG image.

Comment: And if you want the background effects of that JPG - use that JPG. :)

Comment: @BoltClock just fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious as to if its possible. I know I can just put an image in, but it would interesting to have css form the shape to put content in.

Comment: It's always *possible* (you can always just make one element for each pixel) - but it's prohibitively difficult. This is one of those "prohibitively difficult" ones, given how the parts of the pentagram overlap with borders, and how the... weathered (?) effect is hardly just a gradient or five.

Comment: Just by the way, a pentagram (inverted or otherwise) by itself is not really a symbol of death metal.  It's a Pagan thing.  It's used by Satanists and therefore often depicted in death metal, basically because it upsets Christians.  But it generally appears as a [Baphomet](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_7n4EZnpRM6o/TThh45VxYoI/AAAAAAAABTQ/EhUm1j4YWhw/s1600/baphomet.jpg) which is the official symbol of the Church of Satan.  If you really want to promote, get an artist to draw you a real badass baphomet and use your CSS skills for other things.

Comment: right on man, but I just want to take a minimalist approach to a common icon of death, doom and black metal and see if I can come up with an elegant implementation through styling and not through graphics and background images.

Comment: well then here is minimalist approach http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/8FjL2/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well by doing a little bit of Googling, I found [this site](http://csspentagram.com/). By fiddling around a little bit (I pressed F12), I found this:

HTML:

```
<div id="pentagram">
<div id="star_1"></div>
<div id="star_2"></div>
<div id="star_3"></div>
<div id="star_4"></div>
<div id="star_5"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#pentagram{margin:0 auto;margin-top:45px;margin-bottom:75px;height:500px;width:500px;border-radius:500px;border:5px solid #bb0000;position:relative;}#pentagram div{position:absolute;background:#bb0000;width:476px;height:5px;}
#star_1{top:328px;left:12px;}
#star_2{top:183px;left:-38px;transform:rotate(-37deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-37deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-37deg);}
#star_3{top:183px;right:-38px;transform:rotate(37deg);-ms-transform:rotate(37deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(37deg);}
#star_4{top:268px;right:-60px;width:480px !important;transform:rotate(107deg);-ms-transform:rotate(107deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(107deg);}
#star_5{top:268px;left:-60px;width:480px !important;transform:rotate(-107deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-107deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-107deg);}
```

Answer (score 3):

solution to what has been asked here

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/dVp6p/1/)

```
<div id="pentagram"></div>

#pentagram {
  position: absolute;
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-right: 120px solid transparent; 
   border-left: 120px solid transparent; 
   border-bottom: 80px solid black;
  top:100px;
  left:50px;  
}
#pentagram:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-right: 120px solid transparent; 
   border-left: 120px solid transparent; 
   border-top: 80px solid black;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(34deg);
  margin:6px 0 0 -122px;
}

#pentagram:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-top: 120px solid transparent; 
   border-bottom: 120px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 80px solid black;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
  margin:-74px 0 0 -42px;
}
```